# Why does the Reeve ride at the end of the procession?

Tags: geoffrey-chaucer, the-canterbury-tales

In Chaucer's *The Canterbury Tales*, we're told that the Reeve always rides at the end of the procession of pilgrims going to Canterbury:

> And evere he rood the hyndreste of oure route.
>   (line 622; [the text is available online](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CT/1:1.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)).

Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

The yellow bile or *choler* of this “sclendre colerik man” is at least partly expressed in suspicious wariness of others. In his position as Reeve ([estate manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeve_(England)#cite_ref-1)), this has served both “his lorde” and himself well, preventing them from being cheated:

> Ther nas baillif, ne hierde, nor oother hyne,
>   That he ne knew his sleighte and his covyne;
>   They were adrad of hym as of the deeth. ([603–05](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CT/1:1.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext))

So he rides at the rear of the company because that is the best way to keep an eye on everyone else. There are some pretty shady and scurvy characters among the *route* of his *nyne and twenty* fellow-pilgrims, so to some extent this vigilance is warranted; but more importantly it is a characteristic of his temperament that he cannot well turn off even where it is inappropriate—wherein, precisely, lies the essence of humor of character, according to a theory most famously put into practice by Ben Jonson, and best articulated by Henri Bergson in his essay “Le Rire” (“[Laughter](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4352/4352-h/4352-h.htm)”).

Comment: Nice answer. I have a few unanswered Canterbury Tales questions if you are interested.